# PRF that can be distinguished after $k$ queries?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, distinguisher

In adaptive attacks, if we design poorly, adversary can modify his queries and break the given pseudo random function (that is being able to distinguish it from uniform randomness).

Is there a poor way to design a PRF such that in one round of query, the adversary cannot distinguish but in two rounds the adversary can?

How about adversary failing to break at $k-1$ queries but breaking at $k$th query?

Comment: "generator (that" $\: \mapsto \:$ "function family (that" $\;\;\;$ ? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: ???? what are you saying?

Comment: Should $\:$ "generator (that" $\:$ be replaced with $\:$ "function family (that" $\;\;\;$ ? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: should it be? I dont know but I am thinking this formulation is valid but why do you say so?

Comment: What would "queries" mean for a pseudo random generator? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Do you know answer to this post?

Answer (score 1):

A [$k$-wise independent hash family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-independent_hashing) has the property that the joint distribution of $h(x_1), h(x_2), \ldots, h(x_k)$ is uniform when $h$ is chosen uniformly from the family (and $x_i$'s are distinct). Such families exist unconditionally (for fixed $k$), are efficient, and satisfy the condition you give.

The simplest example of a 1-universal function is $F(k,x) = x \oplus k$. Clearly the output of $F$ on one point is uniform (it's a one-time pad) but with two queries $F$ can be easily distinguished from a random function.

Comment: What will the adversaries adaptive query be? is it x+k?

Comment: Do you know how to break one-time pad when the same key is used twice? This is the same problem.

For the general case, you don't need adaptive queries to distinguish a $k$-wise independent function (family) from random. Any $k+1$ distinct (static) queries will do.

Comment: same key k is used twice for x and y? you get x+k and y+k. I am looking for something adaptive

Comment: If you are looking for a function that is strong against nonadaptive queries and single adaptive queries (whatever a single adaptive query means), but weak against two adaptive queries, how about a random involulation (that is, a function that is constrained by $F(k, F(k,x)) = x$.  For functions that can take $k-1$ adaptive queries, generalize this to a function for which $F^k(x) = x$ (mostly, if $k$ isn't a divisor of the range, we can do this only most of the time)

Comment: @poncho I tried that for something explicit but unsuccessful could you elaborate your writeup?

Comment: Good point, poncho. $k$-wise independence doesn't imply robustness to $k$ *adaptive* queries. Maybe you should expand your comment to an answer.